# Distribution theory for QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions

For what purpose to introduce distribution theory for quantum mechanics?

If I'm not mistaken, the problem originated with finding eigenfunctions for the position operator in such a way that the solution could be normalized, according to the probability interpretation of the wave function.
For this to be valid, it's necessary that:

$$\| \psi \|_2^2 := \int_{\mathbb R^N} \overline \psi  \ \psi \ dx < \infty$$

So, as I understood it, the idea is to generalize the concept of "norm" with the pairing:

$$u_f(\phi) = \int _{\mathbb R^N} \overline f \phi \ dx$$

where:

- $\phi \in {\cal C}^\infty_0 (\mathbb R^N; \mathbb C) \equiv { \cal D}(\mathbb R^N)$
  is any compactly supported smooth function, equipped with a specific convergence notion (by sequences).
- $u_f : {\cal D}(\mathbb R^N) \to \mathbb C$ is a **distribution**, that is a (sequentially) continuous linear functional.

In this way, $|u_f(\phi)|< \infty$, even for a much more irregular function $f$, like the eigenfunction of the position operator.

Have I said at least something right?
I have still some questions:

1. Is the number $u_f(\phi)$ independent of the choice of $\phi \in \cal D(\mathbb R^N)$?
2. Is there a link between the seminorm concept?
3. Why is convergence for distributions called "weak
   "?

Comment: Hi ric.san. Tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formalism here is that of a so-called [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space).

> If I'm not mistaken, the problem originated with finding eigenfunctions for the position operator in such a way that the solution could be normalized, according to the probability interpretation of the wave function.

This isn't quite right.  Even with the introduction of distribution theory, the generalized eigenfunctions of operators with continuous spectra cannot be assigned a meaningful norm and therefore do not give rise to physically realizable states.

Nevertheless, as noted by Dirac and the generations of students who followed him, these "non-normalizable eigenstates" are often extremely useful computational tools. They are not elements of the Hilbert space underlying the theory, so Gelfand and others turned to distribution theory to formalize their existence.

> So, as I understood it, the idea is to generalize the concept of "norm" with the pairing:
> $$u_f(\phi) = \int _{\mathbb R^N} \overline f \phi \ dx$$

This is the right thought, but it's too limited.  We want to define distributions as linear (or conjugate-linear) maps from some suitable domain of test functions $\mathcal D$ to $\mathbb C$.  Integration against some kernel $f$ is an *example* of a distribution (provided that $f$ satisfies some regularity conditions which depend on your choice of $\mathcal D$), but there are distributions which cannot be framed in this way.  Most notably, the Dirac distribution
$$\Delta_a:\phi \mapsto \phi(a)$$
which simply evaluates a test function at a point cannot be expressed as integration against a function $f$.  We often write $\Delta_a(\phi) \equiv \int \delta(x-a) \phi(x) \mathrm dx$ to superficially cast it as integration against a kernel $\delta$, but we are to understand that $\delta$ is not actually a function, and that this is merely a notational trick.

Now to your questions.

> Is the number $u_f(\phi)$ independent of the choice of $\phi\in \mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$?

Certainly not.  $u_f(\phi)$ is not a generalization of the norm; if anything, it is a generalization of the *inner product* such that $f$ need not be an element of the Hilbert space.  An example would be $f(x)=e^{ikx}$, in which case $u_f$ is the Fourier distribution $\phi \mapsto \int e^{-ikx} \phi(x) \mathrm dx$.  It should be fairly obvious that this depends entirely on which $\phi$ the distribution acts on.

> Is there a link between the seminorm concept?

Not an obvious one that I can think of.

> Why is convergence for distributions called "weak "?

On a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, a sequence $x_n$ is said to converge to $x$ in the weak sense if, for all $y\in \mathcal H$, we have that the sequence of complex numbers $\langle x_n,y\rangle$ converges to $\langle x,y\rangle$. On the other hand, $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the *strong* sense if $\Vert x_n-x\Vert$ converges to zero.

Without getting too deep [in the weeds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-the-weeds) with the technical definitions of the weak and strong topologies, you can understand the motivation for the names by the fact that strong convergence of a sequence implies weak convergence, but the reverse is not true.

The weak convergence of distributions can be understood by way of analogy with the above; a sequence of distributions $u_k$ converges to $u$ if, for all test functions $\phi\in \mathcal D$, we have that $u_k(\phi)\rightarrow u(\phi)$.  In general there is no natural sense of strong convergence on the space of distributions, because the space of distributions is generally not equipped with a norm.